# Java substring using lastindexOf return a specific length

Tags: java, string, substring, lastindexof

I'm using JAVA and I have a string called example that looks like;

```
example = " id":"abcd1234-efghi5678""tag":"abc" "
```

NOTE: I have't escaped the "'s using \ but you get the idea..

...I want to just return;

abcd1234

...I've been trying using substring

```
example = (example.substring(example.lastIndexOf("id\":\"")+5));
```

(because this string could be anywhere in a HTML/JSON File) which kinda works all the lastIndexOf does is find it and then keep everything AFTER it - i.e it returns;

abcd1234-efghi5678""tag":"abc"

Basically I need to find the lastIndexOf based on the string and limit it returns afterwards - I found that I could do it another substring command like this;

```
example = (example.substring(example.lastIndexOf("id\":\"")+5));
example = example.substring(0,8);
```

...but it seems messy. Is there any way of using lastIndexOf and also setting a max length at the same time - it's probably something really simple that I can't see due to staring at it for so long.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `substring` twice. Use the found index twice instead:

```
int idx = example.lastIndexOf("id\":\"");
example = example.substring(idx + 5, idx + 13);
```

Or, if the length is dynamic, but always ends with `-`:

```
int start = example.lastIndexOf("id\":\"");
int end = example.indexOf('-', start);
example = example.substring(start + 5, end);
```

In real code, you should of course always check that the substring is found at all, i.e. that `idx` / `start` / `end` are not `-1`.

Comment: Yes that worked - I like how I can use the tags for start and end in the later substring command - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to find the specific substring:

```
String regex = "^id[^a-z0-9]+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-.*$";
Matcher p = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(example);

String result = null;
if (p.matches()) {
    result = p.group(1);
}

System.out.println(result); //outputs exactly "abcd1234"
```

The pattern uses a capturing group that matches `id` followed by non-alphanumeric characters and preceding `-`.